# Coset of principal genus vs. subgroup of squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I have been reading Cox's "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$" and I have been a bit confused about a seeming conflict between a statement in the proof of Theorem 3.15(ii) (page 49) and Lemma 3.17 (page 50).

For context, Theorem 3.15(ii) shows that for a negative integer $D \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 4$, the principal genus mod $D$ consists exactly of the square elements in the form class group $\mathcal C(D)$. Lemma 3.17 is an intermediate step which shows that the map $\Psi: (\mathbb Z/D \mathbb Z)^\times \rightarrow \{\pm 1\}^\mu$ given by the tuple of evaluations at the assigned characters, is surjective and its kernel is precisely the subgroup $H$ of values represented by the principal form.

Now, at the end of page 50, it is said that in the case when $D$ is even (i.e., $D=-4n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$), the subgroup $H$ might be larger than the subgroup of squares in the group $\ker \chi$ (which is an exactly equality for odd $D$). But if we show that the principal genus consists only of square elements (as Theoem 3.15(ii) does), then isn't it automatic that $H$ (which is the image of any class in the principal genus under the map $\Phi: \mathcal C(D) \rightarrow \ker \chi/H$) consists only of squares? So basically my question is the following:

Does the subgroup $H$ of $\ker \chi \subset (\mathbb Z/D \mathbb Z)^\times$ represented by the principal form, always consist of the squares in $\ker \chi$? (In that case, is the statement at the end of page 50 basically saying that we don't know this fact at that stage?) Or am I misunderstanding something and there are explicit counterexamples (if so, what are some of them?) to the expectation that $H$ always consists of squares, irrespective of the parity of $D$?

Thank you.

Comment: he refers the reader to Exercise 3.11,   page 68 in my edition, probably about page 73 in yours.  At the exercise, he refers to Ireland and Rosen,  section 4.1.  In 3.11(ii) he notes $H_1$  involves $2^{a+2}.$  It comes down to this:  odd squares are $1 \pmod 8$

Comment: @Will Jagy Ah, thanks for pointing this out, so it does turn out that it is the subgroup of squares in both cases, and I was misinterpreting the statement with "might be larger than the subgroup of squares" at the end of page 50, after all.